# how to disallow a web crawler from downloading php code?

Tags: php, html, security, web-crawler

I ran a simple web crawler on my site which downloaded the entire sites source code.

Is it possible to prevent web crawlers from downloading/saving any php code from your site?  Without encryption, is there a simple disallow rule in robots.txt or can web crawlers generally download the entire source code of any website?

Comment: They most definitely cannot download the PHP source code, unless your server isn't processing PHP, in which case your site is utterly broken anyways. Webcrawlers see the same thing as any other user sees, the *output* of your PHP.

Comment: bots can't download your php code

Comment: Can we see the URL in question, OP?

Comment: I am fairly new to web crawlers - the code was from a post on stackoverflow - I have added it to the question.  This code seems to download my entire site including php code to results.txt

Comment: He's running the crawler himself, on his server, through file_get_contents, therefore it's grabbing the file contents scripts and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're accessing pages from their web locations you should be fine. For those confused, the question asker seems to be **running their own crawler** and because it's getting local addresses, it's grabbing the files locally.

So make sure it's accessing it through http to prevent the source code from being crawled.

Specifically for your code, before recursing to the function again check the url is absolute from your domain (starts with http://domain.tld), and make it that way if it isn't (simply tacking it on won't work if you have relative urls on your site, it will be more complicated, look into changing relative urls to absolute with PHP.)

Comment: Your right it was grabbing the local files

Comment: so why did you say robots.txt btw.

Comment: @akshayb he copy pasted the code for his crawler, so he doesn't quite understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

A Web Crawler only downloads the html content of the site. It has no access whatsoever to your php script.

Comment: Rubbish. It can have it if your server config is incorrect.

Comment: The download from the spider showed all code including php, can you tell me which server settings I should be looking at to prevent this?

Comment: @Marcin, I think we can take it as read that akshayb meant "when PHP is configured to work" `:)`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski This is possible if we tweak the crawler along with incorrect configuration of the server, which I don't think subject matter of question. OP can you provide the link of the page ?

Comment: I have added the web crawler code which came from a post on stackoverflow - this seems to download my entire sites source code including php code

Comment: I repeat, can you provide the link of page you are trying to download and is returning php ?

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure that you've got `.php` extensions to the files, your site will be rendering the PHP source code when it serves it, a robot won't be able to download the source. It'll just see the HTML that the PHP generates, like everyone else that visits the site.